# add column headers from array to datatables jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am creating a Datatable in jquery. I have an array of strings which contain the titles for the headers. I want to add these titles to the datatable. How can I do this?

Here is my code:-

html code:-

```
<table border="1" id="mDataTable" class="display" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

jquery code:-

```
 var columnArray = jsonArray[1];
                    var titleArray = [];
                    for (var j = 0; j < columnArray.length; j++) {

                        var parsedJson = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(columnArray[j]))
                        var mTitles = parsedJson["name"];
                        titleArray.push(mTitles);

                    }


                    $('#mDataTable').DataTable({

                        "columns": titleArray
                    });
```

the `titleArray = ["America", "India", "China", "Japan"]`

the

```
jquery[1] = "Columns":[{"name":"ID","field":"id"},{"name":"America","field":"america"},{"name":"India","field":"india"},{"name":"China","field":"china"},{"name":"Japan","field":"japan"}],
```

Doing the above I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '10' in America
```

**EDIT**

With CerilBoss's answer I get a table like this

[image]

I am new to jquery and would appreciate any help.

Comment: whats inside `jsonArray[1]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

append the header data before initializing the `dataTable`

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/j1LuafLm/1/)

**CODE**

```
var jsonArray = {"Columns":[{"name":"ID","field":"id"},{"name":"America","field":"america"},{"name":"India","field":"india"},{"name":"China","field":"china"},{"name":"Japan","field":"japan"}]};
var columnArray = jsonArray['Columns'];
var titleArray = [];
$('table thead tr').empty();
for (var j = 0; j < columnArray.length; j++) {
    var parsedJson = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(columnArray[j]))
    var mTitles = parsedJson["name"];
    $('table thead tr').append("<th>"+ mTitles +"</th>");
};
$('table').DataTable();
```

**UPDATED** [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/j1LuafLm/2/)

**UPDATED CODE**

```
var jsonArray = {"Columns":[{"name":"ID","field":"id"},{"name":"America","field":"america"},{"name":"India","field":"india"},{"name":"China","field":"china"},{"name":"Japan","field":"japan"}]};
var columnArray = jsonArray['Columns'];
var titleArray = [];
for (var j = 0; j < columnArray.length; j++) {
    var temp = {};
    temp['title'] = columnArray[j]["name"];
    titleArray.push(temp);
};
$('table').DataTable({ "columns": titleArray});
```

**UDPATE**

Check this latest [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/j1LuafLm/3/)

Comment: Also, could you help me with how to add the table data which is in the same array format?

Comment: for data your array format has to be different. means, it should have array of array of objects

Comment: something like `{"Rows": [[{"name": "1", "field": "id"}, {"name": "America", "field": "america"}, {"name": "India", "field": "india"}, {"name": "China", "field": "china"}, {"name": "Japan", "field": "japan"} ], [{"name": "2", "field": "id"}, {"name": "America", "field": "america"}, {"name": "India", "field": "india"}, {"name": "China", "field": "china"}, {"name": "Japan", "field": "japan"} ] ] }`

Comment: I worked it out thanks. I had a doubt about your previous answer though. I was refering the link https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html . Can't I do sometihing like that to reduce the code?  My table somehow looks different than the one in your Fiddle code

Comment: I have mentioned my table in my question. Can you cjeck

Comment: Yes. This is what I wanted. Also my data is as follows :- "Data":[{"east":12,"west":34,"north":45,"south":70},{"east":34,"west":56,"north":12,"south":78},{"east":7,"west":23,"north":87,"south":90},{"east":23,"west":33,"north":54,"south":12},{"east":23,"west":45,"north":12,"south":67},{"east":76,"west":23,"north":12,"south":56},{"east":12,"west":34,"north":45,"south":70},{"east":12,"west":34,"north":45,"south":70},{"east":12,"west":34,"north":45,"south":70},{"east":12,"west":34,"north":45,"south":70},{"east":12,"west":34,"north":45,"south":70}}]}. how do I add this?

Comment: your data set has to be changed to array of array format.

Comment: I did it.. Something like this ` //Add data
         var dataArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Data.length; i++) {
            var temp = {};
            temp['east'] = data.Data[i]["east"];
            temp['west'] = data.Data[i]["west"];
            temp['north'] = data.Data[i]["north"];
            temp['south'] = data.Data[i]["south"];
            dataArray.push(temp);
        }`

But I get an error like `Datatables requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0`

Comment: this works. But the data in the first row should be in the third row. DO i need to apply some sorting?

Comment: yes. you should disable datatable default sorting.. check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/j1LuafLm/4/)

Comment: It worked. thank you so much for your time and patience. Really appreciate it